# How to use a list as a dictionary key without adding complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, time-complexity

So my problem is that i need to add a list as a key in dictionary, hence we can not do that since it's mutable , i want a way to do that without casting to a tuple or a string because that add a lot of complexity to my algorithme since the algorithme i have is recursive.

Here is a small part of my algorithme :

```py
global_memory = dict()

def advanced(nm , l , player , first= True ) :
    list_possibilities = possibilities(nm , l , player )
    n,m = nm
    costs = []
    # if first call that reinstialize the globale memory
    global global_memory
    if first == True : 
        global_memory = dict() 
    if len(list_possibilities) == 0 :
        return 0
    for pos in list_possibilities :
        if (str(pos), player) in global_memory :
            cost = global_memory[(str(pos) , player)]
        else :
            cost = advanced(nm , pos,oppositePlayer(player) , False )
            global_memory[(str(pos),player)] = cost
        costs.append(cost)
    return bestValue(costs)
```

as you see every time i check if str(pos) is in the dict it takes a time to cast than to check and that's add up to the complexity. Anyway to do that without casting ?
Thank you.
Have a good day.

PS : First time using global variable , does globals add to the complexity ?

Comment: What data type is `pos`? A list?

Comment: No, there is no direct way to use a list as a dictionary key. Converting it to a tuple is probably more efficient than converting it to a string.

Comment: @Mortz yes a list

Comment: @JohnColeman does the global adds to the complexity ? because my main problem is the time complexity since what i m asked for is to pas some tests in a given time

Comment: Using a global wouldn't be the problem. It is probably the algorithm itself which is the problem. Perhaps there is a nonrecursive approach that you could use.

Comment: @JohnColeman no not really it is what they ask us to do , dynamic recursive algorithme. this algorithme comparing to the normal algorithme is 10 times better for some tests but there are some tests that can not pass due to the high complexity.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to check what portions are slow?

Comment: @Mortz Idk what are you talking about so assume the answer is no ! Can you give more context please ?

Comment: Technically, converting your position to a string will not change the time complexity, as your position is likely bounded by a constant. There are still faster ways of doing it than string building, I'm sure. Have you considered hashing the values you need into a key?

Comment: @Berthur can you please give me a more details about how can i hash it ?

Comment: Using a hash function, you can hash together any number of primitive variables you want into a key that will be probabilistically unique, then use that as key in your dictionary: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function . Another option is to use multiple maps, sparse arrays or other data structures.

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) and [snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/)

Comment: @Berthur: Even hashing the elements has the same complexity as the string construction.

Comment: @DavisHerring Exactly, see my previous comment. So either OP is asking about improving the runtime and not the time complexity, or he should address the entire recursive algorithm logic (which we can't easily help with, as he has not explained it) and not the string creation.

Answer (score 0):

It **is** possible to smuggle a `list` in as a dictionary key without copying it:

```
class JustUsChickens:
  def __init__(self,l): self.l=l
  def __hash__(self):
    ret=0
    for x in self.l: ret^=hash(x)  # TODO: better hash combination
    return ret
  def __eq__(self,o): return isinstance(o,JustUsChickens) and self.l==o.l

my_list=[1,2,3]
juc=JustUsChickens(my_list)
d={juc:4}
```

Note that assigning to `juc.l` or modifying `my_list` will **break** `d`.

It's also hard to imagine a circumstance under which this would actually have better performance: in my test, the user-written `__hash__` took almost **twice** as long to execute as just writing `d={tuple(my_list):4}` (and doing better than `^=` would make it even slower).  One possible exception is if your lists are so long that storing an extra `tuple` copy of them (even reusing the same element objects!) is prohibitively expensive.